# SQL Server content from diffrent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to get the content of tables that match specific condition for their name,

for example something like:

```
select id //lets assume that all of the tables have id column
from (all tables that their names starts with 'p' )
```

so i except the output will be something like:

10 records from 'projects' table + 24 records from 'people' records etc...

Comment: That's a weird requirement, why do you need this? Use dynamic sql if you really want

Comment: This is usually an indication that what should have been modelled as *data* has instead been modelled as *metadata* (e.g. within column or table names). It would usually be better to fix the model so that data you want to query over is placed in queryable locations (e.g. as data values *within* columns)

Comment: Whilst you can write metadata queries in SQL, it's decidedly non-trivial to "mix levels", as you try to do here, where you're trying to combine a metadata query (tables with names starting with p) with a data query (values from the id column)

Comment: Which version of SQL server?

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: i need that because i delete records from specific tables from outer program through api , and just want to check that with a query to ensure i deletetd the right records from the right tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact, that this requirement smells intensively you might use dynamically created SQL and `EXEC`. From `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` you can get meta data quite easily. The query will get all tables, where the name starts with `p`

The statement created looks like

```
          SELECT 'Tbl1' AS TheTable,ID FROM [Tbl1] 
UNION ALL SELECT 'Tbl2' AS TheTable,ID FROM [Tbl2] 
UNION ALL SELECT ...
```

The result will be a list containing the table's name and the value of the column `id`.

You can try this

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql=STUFF
(
    (
    SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT ''' +  TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TheTable,ID FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'p%'
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,11,'');

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC(@sql);
```

After checking the command via `PRINT` you can take away the `--` before `EXEC`